# Centering one product on a single page

Tags: customization, css

I have one minor issue that I cannot resolve and that is being able to center a single product on a page. I have managed to research this site and others and been able to center the text however I cannot center the image and the text on the page.

I'm fairly confident with editing but just need some guidance on how this is done. I am using woocommerce to possibly sell a single item on our site. Everything else is ok.

Here's the page: `http://www.jasperstearooms.com/?post_type=product`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To center with CSS you have to stop it from floating `left` then put `auto` on the margin-left and margin-right.

```
ul.products li.product, .woocommerce-page ul.products li.product {
    float: none;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Can you add another class when there is only 1 item?

If you can't there is a way in CSS to target a single child using [:only-child](http://tympanus.net/codrops/css_reference/only-child/).

```
ul.products li.product:only-child, .woocommerce-page ul.products li.product:only-child {
    float: none;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

You can center the `Vouchers` with this, but there is no css only way to know if there is only one item below. If you add a class via javascript it would help differentiate 1 vs. >1.

```
.woocommerce .woocommerce-ordering, .woocommerce .woocommerce-result-count {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

Comment: Why did this get a down vote?  The OP is arguably off-topic, jgraup appears to answer the question, however.

Comment: Hey jgraup, your second suggestion worked thank you. if you visit the link again you will see that the single item has now moved to the center using:
ul.products li.product:only-child, .woocommerce-page ul.products li.product:only-child {
    float: none;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
It has left the word "Vouchers" to the left, but that's ok as I wanted the product in the center. Appreciate your time.

Comment: Added a solution to center the `Vouchers` but it does not know how many items are there.